# Broadcast error on querying the test points using coefficients obtained from lstsq

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, least-squares

I am trying to work with [numpy's lstsq](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html?highlight=lstsq#numpy.linalg.lstsq). I have a trainX data set `t` of the shape:

```
400,8
```

and a trainY data set `ty` of shape:

```
400,1
```

The following statement:

```
coff = np.linalg.lstsq(np.vstack([t,np.ones(t.shape[1])]).T,ty,rcond=None)[0]
```

gives me the coefficient of shape:

```
8,1
```

Now, with this model, I want to make queries on the test set `test` of shape :

```
200,8
```

If I do:

```
(coff[:-1] * test).sum(axis=1) + coff[-1]
# mx + c
```

it throws an error `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,1) (200,8)`

Could someone please explain this error? How can I query on the test points?

Comment: `coff = ...` line gives 'Incompatible dimensions' error as `np.vstack(...)` has dimension (8, 401) and `ty` has (400, 1). Do you change `t` and `ty` values before it?